# Java Limit Class array types

Tags: java

I Created an array like this:

```
    Class<? extends AbstractItem>[] itemList = {
            ItemNew.class,
            ItemLoad.class,
            ItemSave.class,
            ItemSetting.class,
            ItemEnd.class
    };
```

but `java` tells me:

```
Cannot create a generic array of Class<? extends AbstractItem>
```

If I don't specify the Class generics `java` warns me with:

```
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized
```

So who is right? and even more why doesn't it allow me to limit the Class types?

edit: the mentioned duplicate is not solving my problem, cause if I do not specify the type of the array, I can create it with compiler warning. So it is indeed possible but I am looking for the right way to achieve this)

Comment: General rule of thumb: Don't combine generics and arrays. You only get headaches.

Comment: i can create it. if i leave it generic. but i was concerned about the compiler warning. the solution for me was to specefie it, what endet me with a error.

Comment: `List<Class<? extends AbstractItem>> classes = Arrays.asList(ItemLoad.class, ItemNew.class);`

Answer (score 0):

The java don't allow create generic array except all type arguments are unbounded wildcards.

Consider the following code:

```
    List<String>[] strings=new List<String>[1];    //1
    List<Integer> integers=Arrays.asList(1);
    Object[] objects=strings;
    objects[0]=integers;
    String s=strings[0].get(0);
    System.out.println(s);      //2
```

See the statement 1,if java allow create the generic type array,the above code will get a exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` on statement 2 whitout any warnings at run-time.This is not correctly ,so the java mustn't create generic type array.

If you change `List<String>[] stringList=new List<String>[1];    //1` to `List<String>[] stringList=new List[1];`,the code will can compile correctly,but the compiler will get a warning like `Unchecked assignment`,of course,your can use  `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to suppress the warning.

In the `JLS 10.6` Array Initializers section,there is a rule:

```
It is a compile-time error if the component type of the array being initialized is not reifiable
```

and the `JLS 4.7` Reifiable Types define what is `reifiable types`,the first one is :

```
It refers to a non-generic class or interface type declaration.
```

Comment: The situation you're describing also arises (at compile time) without any generics (e.g. try it with String[], Object[] and assign a Boolean, it compiles). It's caused by assigning a Whatever[] array to a variable declared Object[], without even getting a compiler warning. In the non-generics situation, at least you get an ArrayStoreException at runtime.